# Replace all occurrences of a word with another in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache

I need to change one word which is there in all URLs linking to my site.
I tried with the following rule but it works fine only when the word is the first one in URL

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo(?:/)?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^[/]?foo[/]?(.*) /bar/$1 [R=permanent,L,NE]
```

When I add wildcard entries to REQ_URI, output is not proper, I am not sure how to handle replacements. www.example.com/abc/def/foo/ghi is rewirtten as www.example.com/bar/abc/def

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/foo(?:/)?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)[/]?foo[/]?(.*) /bar/$1 [R=permanent,L,NE]
```

How do I correct the rewrite rule ?

Comment: To be clear, do you only need to replace `/foo/` with `/bar/` or do you also want to move `/bar/` to the beginning and drop any other parameters after `/foo/`?

Comment: @Wige I need to find and replace foo with bar anywhere in URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/foo/(.*)$ $1/bar/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ bar/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This assumes foo is a folder name. Generally when setting something like this up you want to have some sort of delimiter (in this case the slashes) so that, for example, "food" doesn't become "bard".

Comment: Its working for `www.example.com/abc/foo/bar` but not for `www.example.com/foo/abc`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added an additional rule to handle it being at the start of the URL.